# How to click background for input checkbox?

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I am working on a switch checkbox input and currently the style changes when I click on the switch knob only. But, I cannot figure out how to make the switch style change when the switch input is checked and slider is clicked instead of the knob itself.

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="toggle"/>
<div>
  <label for="toggle"></label>
</div>
```

```css
input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}
/* style switch when 'unchecked' */
div {
  position: relative;
  width: 42px;
  height: 26px;
  background: #cccccc;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
/* style switch knob */
label {
  position: absolute;
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  background: #ffffff;
  top: 2px;
  left: 2px;  
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* style slider and knob when switch is 'checked' */
input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ div label {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(16px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(16px);
  transform: translateX(16px);
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ div {
  background: #0071d0;
}

/* style knob when switch is unchecked. */
label::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '\1F5D9';
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  left: 3px;
  top: -1px;
}

/* style knob when switch is checked. */
input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ div label::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '\2713';
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  left: 5px;
}
```

Can someone take a look and help me with this? Thanks!

Link: https://codepen.io/Zack-Oliver/pen/poqGeYO

Answer (score 1):

Clicking the `label` element has the same effect as clicking the checkbox, but clicking the `div` element which wraps the label has no effect all. So rather than wrap your `label` in a `div`, make the `label` wrap a `span` instead. The `label` needs to **be the wrapper**, if you like. Events bubble up to their parents, so a click anywhere in the `label`, whether the click is on the `span` portion or outside it, has the same effect as clicking the checkbox.

```css
input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}
/* style switch when 'unchecked' */
label {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 42px;
  height: 26px;
  background: #cccccc;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
/* style switch knob */
label>span {
  position: absolute;
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  background: #ffffff;
  top: 2px;
  left: 2px;  
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* style slider and knob when switch is 'checked' */
input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ label>span {
  transform: translateX(16px);
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ label {
  background: #0071d0;
}

/* style knob when switch is unchecked. */
label>span::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: 'n';
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: -2px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

/* style knob when switch is checked. */
input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ label>span::before {
  content: 'y';
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="toggle"/>
<label for="toggle"><span></span></label>
```

However, I prefer this simplified version without a glyph inside the switch.

```css
input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 42px;
  height: 26px;
  background: #cccccc;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

label::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  background: #ffffff;
  top: 2px;
  left: 2px;  
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ label {
  background: #0071d0;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ label::before {
  transform: translateX(16px);
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="toggle"/>
<label for="toggle"></label>
```

Comment: I agree that the switch button without the glyph in just plain easy. But I am just doing this for learning purposes and encountered an unexpected behavior instead.

Answer (score 0):

Just playing around with your code gave me this. As said above, the label needs to be the wrapper.

```css
input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}

/* style switch when 'unchecked' */
div {
  position: relative;
  width: 48px;
  height: 26px;
  background: #cccccc;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

/* style switch knob */
label {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 22px;
  top: 2px;
  left: 2px;  
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* style slider and knob when switch is 'checked' */
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::before {
  transform: translateX(16px);
  background: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
 div:has(input[type="checkbox"]:checked) {
  background: #0071d0;
}

/* style knob when switch is unchecked. */
label::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '\1F5D9';
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  left: 5px;
}

/* style knob when switch is checked. */
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '\2713';
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: white;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="toggle"/>
  <label for="toggle"></label>
</div>
```

Brett's is a nicer answer, though.

Answer (score 0):

To change the switch style when the switch input is checked and the slider is clicked instead of the knob itself, you can modify your HTML and CSS as follows:

```css
/* Add styles for when the input is checked */
.switch-input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

/* Add styles for when the slider is clicked */
.switch:hover .slider {
  background-color: #64B5F6;
}
```

```html
<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" class="switch-input">
  <span class="slider"></span>
</label>
```

Add this in your code and try to run.